# Are photos uploaded automatically to OneDrive from my phone full resolution?

Tags: onedrive, photos, 7.x

There is an option to automatically upload any pictures to OneDrive that you take with your phone (From the Photos hub, select the ellipsis (...), then settings, then turn on Automatically upload to OneDrive).  I have read differing opinions on various websites and I'd like to know the real answer.

Are photos uploaded automatically to OneDrive from my phone full resolution, or are they resized or compressed in some way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, photos are uploaded to OneDrive at a reduced resolution. In my case, photos seem to be all in 539x719. To get the full resolution photos, sync your phone with Zune and they should appear in your Pictures library.

From the [WindowsPhone How-to](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/pictures/upload-pictures-to-the-web.aspx):

> Pictures are uploaded to SkyDrive and other social networks at low resolution. To back up your pictures at full resolution, use the Zune software on your computer. To learn more, see Sync music, pictures, and videos. You can also upload your pictures at full resolution using the SkyDrive app, which is available in Marketplace.

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't apply to Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 6):

If you upload the photos from the Pictures hub, they are downsized so they don't eat your mobile connection. The only way to upload the full-resolution photos is doing it manually from the official [OneDrive app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3).